# Verification: Translating a mathematical problem into symbolic logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

May you tell me if my translation to symbolic logic is correct?

Thank you so much! Here is the problem:

To check that a given integer $n > 1$ is a prime, prove that it is enough to show that $n$ is not divisible by any prime $p$ with $p \le \sqrt{n}$.

$$\forall p \in P ~\forall n \in N ~(p \nmid n \land p\le \sqrt{n}   \land n>1 \rightarrow n \in P )$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the quantifier for the $p$ on the inside, since that is much more readable. Also when it says ít is not divisible by any prime $p$', they mean: there is not *some* prime $p$ bla bla bla...

So:

$$\forall n \in N ((\neg \exists p \in P (p \mid n \land p\le \sqrt{n})   \land n>1) \rightarrow n \in P )$$

You *could* bring the quantifier out, but it would become a lot less readable. Here is what would happen:

$$\forall n \in N ((\neg \exists p \in P (p \mid n \land p\le \sqrt{n})   \land n>1) \rightarrow n \in P ) \Leftrightarrow$$

$$\forall n \in N ((\forall p \in P \neg  (p \mid n \land p\le \sqrt{n})   \land n>1) \rightarrow n \in P ) \Leftrightarrow$$

$$\forall n \in N (\forall p \in P (\neg  (p \mid n \land p\le \sqrt{n})   \land n>1) \rightarrow n \in P ) \Leftrightarrow$$

$$\forall n \in N \exists p \in P (\neg (p \mid n \land p\le \sqrt{n})   \land n>1) \rightarrow n \in P )$$

As you can see, the only reason the quantifier 'stayed' what it was is because it first changed by bringing it outside the negation, and later it changed again by bringing it outside the conditional of which it was the antecedent. Indeed, in the end, this resulting statement is hardly comprehensible, so I would leave it inside right where it was.

Moreover, to be more inline with the text of this exercise, I would do:

$$\forall n \in N (n > 1 \rightarrow (\neg \exists p \in P (p \mid n \land p\le \sqrt{n}) \rightarrow n \in P ))$$

And finally, notice that for any $n > 1$, n is a prime *if and only if* it there is no prime $p \leq \sqrt{x}$ that divides $n$, so:

$$\forall n \in N (n > 1 \rightarrow (\neg \exists p \in P (p \mid n \land p\le \sqrt{n}) \leftrightarrow n \in P ))$$

Or even more readable:

$$\forall n \in N (n > 1 \rightarrow (n \in P \leftrightarrow \neg \exists p \in P (p \mid n \land p\le \sqrt{n}) ))$$

In fact, now that you have a quantifier on one side of a *biconditional*, trying to get it out will be seven more messy and, in the end, incomprehensible.  Leave it in!

Comment: Fantastic answer!  Thank you so much!

Comment: Thinking in the proof, do you think that it is easier to do a proof with a biconditional or with a conditional. In my perspective would be easier with a  conditional because you need to prove it just in one direction, right?

Comment: Second question: analyzing your first line. Can you show me how it will change if instead of moving the existential outside you apply the negation to the existential quantifier and then to the conditional?

Comment: Third question: do you believe that the universal quantifier outside is wrong?

Comment: $Beginner I added the steps showing how to pull out the quantifier.  As to your first question:  What do you have to prove from what? And is this supposed to be a formal logic proof?

Comment: i do not need the proof. I just need to state the problem in logic symbols. I am checking your answer and what you added solved all my doubts. Thank you so much for all your teachings!

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not correct, because your formula reads: *"for all prime numbers $p$ and for all natural numbers $n$ the following is true: if $p \nmid n$ and $p \le \sqrt n$ and $n >1$ then $n$ is prime"*, which is obviously false (just take $p=2$ and $n=9$).

I suggest the following:

$$\forall n \in \Bbb N \Bigg( \Big( \exists p \in P \ \big( (p \mid n) \land (p \le \sqrt n) \land (n > 1) \big) \Big) \to n \notin P \Bigg) .$$

In plain language: *"for all natural numbers $n$ the following is true: if there exist a prime number $p$ such that $p \mid n$ and $p \le \sqrt n$ and if $n > 1$, then $n$ is not prime"*.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate your insight!

Comment: One question. You put the example when p=2, but I wrote $$\forall p \in P ~\forall n \in N ~(p \nmid n \land p\le \sqrt{n}   \land n>1 \rightarrow n \in P )$$ Then to prove that my translation is wrong you would have to show a counterexample that all p do not divide n, not only one p, correct?